# Identifying vertex sequences by a criteria

Tags: r, graph, igraph

I have a list of vertex sequences as follows. This is an output from `all_simple_paths` function.

```
vs <- list(structure(c(B = 1L, C = 3L, C1 = 4L, C2 = 5L, C3 = 6L, X = 7L), class = "igraph.vs"), 
     structure(c(B = 1L, C = 3L, C1 = 4L, C2 = 5L, C3 = 6L, X = 7L, 
                 P = 8L), class = "igraph.vs"), 
     structure(c(B = 1L, C = 3L, C1 = 4L, C2 = 5L, C3 = 6L, X = 7L, 
                 P = 8L, K1 = 19L, K2 = 20L, K3 = 21L), class = "igraph.vs"), 
     structure(c(B = 1L, C = 3L, C1 = 4L, C2 = 5L, C3 = 6L, X = 7L, 
                 P = 8L, I = 24L), class = "igraph.vs"), 
     structure(c(B = 1L, C = 3L, C1 = 4L, C2 = 5L, C3 = 6L, X = 7L, 
                 H = 23L), class = "igraph.vs"), 
     structure(c(B = 1L, I = 24L), class = "igraph.vs"))
vs
[[1]]
+ 6/? vertices, named (deleted):
[1] B  C  C1 C2 C3 X 

[[2]]
+ 7/? vertices, named (deleted):
[1] B  C  C1 C2 C3 X  P 

[[3]]
+ 10/? vertices, named (deleted):
 [1] B  C  C1 C2 C3 X  P  K1 K2 K3

[[4]]
+ 8/? vertices, named (deleted):
[1] B  C  C1 C2 C3 X  P  I 

[[5]]
+ 7/? vertices, named (deleted):
[1] B  C  C1 C2 C3 X  H 

[[6]]
+ 2/? vertices, named (deleted):
[1] B I
```

I want to fetch from the list `vs` only those vertex sequences which don't have the elements of `a` as vetrices in between the root and the leaf.

```
a <- c("K3", "H", "I", "N", "B", "A", "X", "P", "Y", "O", "R", "S")
```

How to do this with `igraph` in `R`?

I this example the desired output is

```
out <- list(structure(c(B = 1L, C = 3L, C1 = 4L, C2 = 5L, C3 = 6L, X = 7L), class = "igraph.vs"), 
           structure(c(B = 1L, I = 24L), class = "igraph.vs"))
out
[[1]]
+ 6/? vertices, named (deleted):
[1] B  C  C1 C2 C3 X 

[[2]]
+ 2/? vertices, named (deleted):
[1] B I
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your sample input and output, this seems to work. First, just write a helper function to see of a vertex is contained in the non-terminal vertices of a path, then use that detection function to filter your main list of interest.

```
does_not_contain <- function(a) {
  function(x) !any(a %in% tail(head(names(x), -1), -1))
}

Filter(does_not_contain(a), vs)
```